# Violin Plot in R using ggplot2 on multiple data columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am new to R, and trying to make violin plots of species count data for various species at each sampling depth.  The data looks like the following

```
    Depth Cd Cf Cl
1  3.6576  0  2  0
2  4.0000  2 13  0
3  4.2672  0  0  0
4 13.1064  0  2  0
5 14.0000  3 17 10
6 17.0000  0  0  0
```

With species in columns 2-5 and depth in column one.  I am attempting to use ggplot2 in R but assume the data are not organized in a way that can be used by ggplot2.  Ideally I would like the depth to be the y-axis and the species along the x-axis, with violin plots for each.  Thank you for your help.
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape your data first:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_dat2 <- my_dat %>% 
  gather(species, val, -Depth) %>% 
  slice(rep(row_number(), val)) %>% 
  select(-val)

ggplot(my_dat2, aes(species, Depth)) +
  geom_violin()
```

[image]

Note that `Cl` only has a single line because you have only a singly depth.

Comment: Thank you all for your help with this. This looks great and fully answers my question. Thanks again! Regards, – Alexander just now   edit   delete

Answer (score 2):

Like you suspected already, you need to reshape your data. Using `tidyr::gather` changes the format from "wide" to "long", which is necessary in this case for plotting species on the x-axis. Furthermore, you need to expand your count data which you can achieve with `slice`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

zz <- "Depth Cd Cf Cl
1  3.6576  0  2  0
2  4.0000  2 13  0
3  4.2672  0  0  0
4 13.1064  0  2  0
5 14.0000  3 17 10
6 17.0000  0  0  0"

my_dat <- read.table(text = zz, header = T)

my_dat %>% 
  gather(species, val, -Depth) %>% 
  slice(rep(row_number(), val)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(species, Depth)) +
  geom_violin(adjust = .5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your method works but the violins all look identical.  With different count data for each species, these should look different.  Do have any suggestions?

Comment: @Alexander Axeman was right, I forgot to expand the count data.

Comment: Thank you all for your help with this.  This looks great and fully answers my question.  Thanks again!  Regards,